# In function 'print_usage': error: expected ')' before 'PROGRAM'

Tags: c

As the title states, I am receiving an error when I try to build my project which states: In function 'print_usage': error: expected ')' before 'PROGRAM'

I am not exactly sure what is causing this error and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lexer.h"

void print_usage();
void load_file(char *filename, char **buffer, size_t *size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    argc--;
    argv++;

    if(argc <= 0) {
        print_usage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(argc > 0) {
        size_t size; /* I'm not using this, but it could be useful. */
        Token token;
        char *buffer = NULL;
        unsigned int token_cnt = 0;

        load_file(*argv, &buffer, &size);
        if(buffer) {
            char *b;  /* editable copy of the buffer pointer */
            b = buffer;
            while(get_token(&b, &token) != TOKEN_EOF) {
                printf("%s: ", id_string[token.id]);
                if(token.str) {
                    printf("\"%s\"\n", token.str);
                    free(token.str);
                }
                else {
                    printf("no string found\n");
                }

                if(token.id != TOKEN_BAD) {
                    token_cnt++;
                }
            }
            printf("\n----------------------\n");
            printf("%u valid tokens found\n", token_cnt);
            printf("----------------------\n");

            free(buffer);
        }
        argc--;
        argv++;
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void print_usage() {

    fprintf(stderr, "Usage:   " PROGRAM " [file]...\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown any definition for `PROGRAM`.

Answer (score 2):

```
argc--;
argv++;
/* Since you just incremented argv, you just lost the program name! */
/* You need argv[0] as the program name to create the error message */

if(argc <= 0) {   
    print_usage( argv[0] );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

```
void print_usage(char* program) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [file]...\n", program);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the syntax for fprintf(), you probably need something more like

```
void print_usage() {

    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [file]...\n", PROGRAM);

    return;
}
```

Assuming PROGRAM is defined as a string somewhere.